# Python-Unicode Error- 'utf-8' can't decode byte in .py file, but can in interactive environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, unicode, visual-studio-2015

**System Info:**

sys.version = 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)

Visual Studio Community 2015: Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3

Python Tools for Visual Studio: 2.2.40623.00

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Django Integration: 2.2.40623.00

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Profiling Support: 2.2.40623.00

**Code:**

```
import nltk
french_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/french.pickle')
text = "J’habite aux États-Unis. Où est-ce que vous habitez? Quel est votre film préféré?"
sentList = french_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print(sentList)
```

**Problem:**

When I run this code line-by-line in Python 64-bit 3.5 Interactive environment, each line processes correctly.

When I try to run the entire program all at once, I get the following error regarding the "text =" line:
*SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec cannot decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte*

**Potentially related:**
I went to the Python docs (https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html) and tried some of their sample code and had a similar issue:

```
répertoire = "/tmp/records.log"
```

works fine in the Python 64-bit 3.5 Interactive environment, but produces the following when run as part of a .py file (doesn't run the rest of the file, including very simple "print" commands that precede it):

*The program '[13644] python.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).*

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this may be happening/how to fix this error?

Comment: What text editor did you use? you may be saving windows code page encoding and not utf-8.

Comment: Are you executing your .py file with the same interpreter as interactive environment? (i.e. via `Python 64-bit 3.5`?)

Comment: **What text editor did I use:**

--**For the "J'habite..." text** I copied it from a translation webpage and pasted it directly into the Visual Studio 2015 text editor.

--**For répertoire text** I copied it from the Python Unicode webpage and pasted it directly into the Visual Studio 2015 text editor.


**Same interpreter as interactive environment:** Yes: sys.version = 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at the squiggly thing in `text = "J’habite ..."` -- it is U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. Encoding that character into `cp1252` produces `"\x92"`. Looks like your source code is encoded in `cp1252` or similar. You should ensure that your source code is encoded in `utf-8`.

Comment: Thanks, John... I copied the text from a webpage and pasted it into visual studio as-was, so I guess it is hard to tell what encoding it was (at least for me, I'm new to Unicode processing). However as part of the debugging process I also turned it into `text = "Jhabite aux états-Unis. O est-ce que vous habitez? Quel est votre film prr?"`where I eliminated all of the non-ascii characters and added back only one that I copied directly from the windows Character map (alt+130) and got the same error. Same problem: works in interactive environment, but not in the .py. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to tell the Visual Studio 2015 text editor that you'd like to use utf-8 encoding when saving .py files. I don't use VS so I can't help you with that.